# Grant tfs build to execute sharepoint cmdlet

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, tfs, build

I use TFS Build which is configured with a service account.

I've modified the worklow template to execute a powershell script.

The powershell is launched but on sharepoint cmdlet I have an "access denied error".

So I tested the script with run as different user (using tfs build service account) and it works.

The tfs service account SpShelleAdmin, local admin and farm admin.

I need help.

PS : Get-SpSolution works

Comment: I have written a blog post on executing powershell in the build: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-14-Execute-a-PowerShell-script.aspx. Does that help?

Comment: I use this blog to test Tfs build and deploy sharepoint solutions. My account service can only execute "get method" with TFS BUILD

Answer (score 0):

How have you implemented the support for executing powershell?
 You could implement a custom activity that actually does the powershell invoking by using the `System.Management.Automation` namespace (a very nice example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563262/how-to-make-c-sharp-powershell-invoke-member-thread-safe)). Just surround the implementation with the Impersonation class presented [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-9-Impersonate-activities-%28run-under-other-credentials%29.aspx).
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749769/tfs-invokeprocess-to-run-under-other-credentials) post if it gets you any help.

Comment: I try to impersonate the script but still the same thing. If I run as different (using my account service), it works and with tfs build it doesn't work.